# soapClient.Login to Acumatica in Windows Forms app fails after deployment. "An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https.."

Tags: acumatica

A Windows Forms application using Contract SOAP to Acumatica works fine on a development machine.

soapClient.Login with exactly the same parameters on a production server (Windows 2008) crashes with an error message:

Error Message: An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://XXX.acumatica.com/entity/Default/17.200.001. This could be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

Stack trace:
Server stack trace:
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]:
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at AcmtIntegrator.AcumaticaWSDL.DefaultSoap.Login(String name, String password, String company, String branch, String locale)
at AcmtIntegrator.AcumaticaWSDL.DefaultSoapClient.Login(String name, String password, String company, String branch, String locale) in D:\C2019\AcumaticaIntegrator\AcumaticaIntegrator\Connected Services\AcumaticaWSDL\Reference.cs:line 49298
at AcmtIntegrator.frmExtractLists.LoopAction(String lcAction, String lcExtractType, Boolean& llSuccess) in D:\C2019\AcumaticaIntegrator\AcumaticaIntegrator\frmExtractLists.cs:line 134, Source: mscorlib, InnerException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.,

Answer (score 1):

Two fix were changed to make it work:

1. WSDL service reference was replaced to point to the Acumatica production URL, and
2. Security protocol was set to TLS 1.2:
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Thanks to all who tried to help.